# css vertical align text middle with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

i'm rendering divs within a loop. each div has a text (could be long- which means overflow: hidden is needed.)
[image]

As you can see the text on the left side is not vertical aligned middle.
I searched for an answer and every solution i found which made the left one vertical align middle, caused trouble to the first one, like in this case where the text of the right div is not display from the beggining ("***This is my desc..."): 
[image]

The html code is:

```
<div class="js-recent-item recent-item" data-view-url="{{url}}">
    {{#if isReport}}
    <label class="report-card-title" title="{{title}}">{{title}}</label>
    <div class="no-sides-padding report-container">
    <div class="report-card-text Aligner" title="{{description}}">{{description}}</div>
 </div>
 {{/if}}
</div>
```

The css:

```
.report-card-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.Aligner-item {
  max-width: 50%;
}
.Aligner-item--top {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.Aligner-item--bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

I've tried to solve this with flexbox and with table-cell and didn't succeeded.
I will be happy to get your advises.

Thanks,
Ella.

************** UPDATE: The solution: *********************

```
 {{#if isReport}}
                                                <label class="report-card-title" title="{{title}}">{{title}}</label>
                                                <div class="report-container">
                                                    <div class="report-card-text" title="{{description}}">{{description}}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            {{/if}}
```

The CSS:

```
    .report-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 122px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.report-card-text{
    .card-text;
    padding : 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 23px;  
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try changing the class to `Aligner-item` and add a div around it with the class `Aligner`, since you've copied it from https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/ , might as well see the class they used. :P

Comment: @ishaan you got eagle eyes :p

Comment: as i mentioned i searched for an answer in google :)
This it not solving the problem since the width is not my problem and if i try the align top/bottom the left div's text appear on top, and not in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `span` inside the `label` and give it a `max-height` and `overflow: hidden`, and for the description you set a `max-height`/`overflow: hidden` on the `report-card-text`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.js-recent-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}

.report-card-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 26px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.report-card-title span {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.report-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 26px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.report-card-text {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;   /*  use "auto" if to be able to scroll  */
}
```

```html
<div class="js-recent-item recent-item" data-view-url="{{url}}">
  <label class="report-card-title" title="{{title}}">
    <span>title 1 </span>
  </label>
  <div class="no-sides-padding report-container">
    <div class="report-card-text" title="{{description}}">
      description 1 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="js-recent-item recent-item" data-view-url="{{url}}">
  <label class="report-card-title" title="{{title}}">
    <span>first title title title title title title title title title last </span>
  </label>
  <div class="no-sides-padding report-container">
    <div class="report-card-text Aligner" title="{{description}}">
      first description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description last
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, maybe i was not clear but the problem is with the description and not the title.... the title will be always 1 word...

Comment: @user1165147 Updated my answer

Comment: ok, your answer helped me. Since i cant use scrollbar (requirements) i succeeded using overflow hidden. i will update the solution in the question. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Asons's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361198/22302305), here's a minimal example with text ellipse:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.item1,
.item2 {
  flex: 1
}


/* Magic starts here*/

.wrapper {
  width: 0;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border: solid 1px black;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.content {
  text-align: center;

  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* --- remove if you don't want ellipsis */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  /* --- */


  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;

}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper item1">
    <div class="content">Short content</div>
  </div>


  <div class="wrapper item2">
    <div class="content">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
  </div>
```

[Jsfiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/9bh2q8mj/)